# ¿Cómo guardar posición al cliquear en los artículos de una tienda?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, enlaces-ancla

Me preguntaba como se puede guardar la posición al hacer click en una imagen, es decir, cuando presionas el botón, este te lleva a una url diferente pero cuando vuelva hacia atrás, a la página donde están todos los productos quiero que me establezca por la parte en la que me quedé yo, no sé si me explico. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué no los navegadores ya hacen ésto por defecto? Siempre creí que sí, pues lo he visto con todas las páginas y hasta en webs que he hecho yo y nunca he implementado nada adicional.

Answer (score 1):

Si te he entendido bien lo quieres es volver a la página tal y como la dejaste en el paso anterior. Si es así puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
history.back();
```

o también:

```
history.go(-1);
```

El '.go' lo podrías variar para que volviera, por ejemplo en un formulario 1,2,3... los pasos que tu consideres hacia atrás, por ejemplo: 'history.go(-3);'. Para utilizar esto por ejemplo lo puedes colocar así en tu input:

```
 <input name="volver" onclick="history.back()" type="submit" value="volver"/>
```

o también:

```
 <button onclick="history.back()">Volver</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si creas un

```
<a href="#MiSegundaFoto">
```

El elemento con id="MiSegundaFoto" se va a añadir a la url.

No me acuerdo si estas url se guardan en el historial. De no ser así utiliza la api para añadir la página al historial tras hacer click.

Puedes obtener el elemento por id, añadirle un addEventListener y en click llamas a la función que te añada la url de la página actual al historial.

En la web de Mozilla tienes la documentación de history